# PHP is not run from Apache when php.ini is loaded

Tags: php, apache

I have compiled and installed Apache 2.2.19 and PHP 5.3.6 in CentOS 5.5.

I modified httpd.conf to process .php files with php, and it was indeed working as i could see by creating a simple page with `<?php phpinfo() ?>` in it: the PHP configuration was correctly displayed.

However I noticed among the configuration info that there was no loaded configuration file (php.ini). I need to include ldap and other functionalities, by modifying the include_path variable in a configuration file. Thus I added a php.ini file in the location searched by php, and I modified the include_path variable inside it.

Now is the real problem: when restarting httpd and going back to my simple php page, i only see the text content of the file, that is, `<?php phpinfo() ?>`. Il looks like php is not correctly called from httpd. However when entering `echo "<?php phpinfo() ?>" | php` in command line, I correctly get the PHP configuration information.

What is wrong here? How can httpd not call PHP correctly because of a PHP configuration file? Where should I look inside this php.ini?

Comment: PHP under command line and php under mod_php (assuming your not using FPM) can have different configurations and build options. Were they compiled at the same time and using the same options?

Comment: I believe you should include php the normal way without stating anything about `php.ini` and edit the php.ini used by the php installed

Comment: @James yes they were, there is only one PHP installation.

Comment: @Sherif I would have liked to do that but there is no php.ini in the source package.

Comment: @Sherif correction, there are some :) I will try this now.

Comment: @Sherif ..And that's working :) Please make your comment an answer so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a SELinux issue, what's the result of

```
ls -Z /etc/php.ini
```

Get you something like this?

```
-rw-r--r--  root root system_u:object_r:etc_t          /etc/php.ini
```